# I can't get the desired output voltage

Tags: voltage, buck, boost, converter, output

[image][image]This is a simulation of a buck boost converter.  I want to get -12V as the 
output voltage , but I get -1.148V.

I checked the PWM and the duty cycle and it is right.

I think that my problem in the hardware, but I can't understand
why.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Your simulation shows nearly -12V.  Are you getting -1.15V on the real circuit?

Comment: Classic newbie mistake -- trying to use an N-channel MOSFET as a high-side switch.

Comment: Is the MOSFET a FDS5690?

Comment: @DaveTweed - it's not a mistake given how the gate is driven (apart from the gate drive voltage being too low).

Comment: in the real circuit i get -1.148v  , and im using the FQP30N06L mosfet n channel

Comment: Show the exact circuit that you built and I bet it's not the same as your simulation.

Comment: From the picture it doesn't look like you have connected the raspberry gnd to the nmos' source like you do in the simulation. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Also, why the resistor between gate and source? You should review the wiring on the breadboard.

Comment: Show the exact circuit diagram - what you have shown is a photo of what you built.

Comment: That's how I connected the raspberrypi pins

Comment: You have drawn two grounds for your Pi, effectively shorting your circuit.

Comment: When responding to someones comment you should use either the "answer"-button or @SalhaShomary, so the person gets a notification. The circuit in the drawn wiring diagram does not match the one in the simulation where there is no connection between RasPi-GND and Vin-GND.

Comment: Actually, the breadboard setup doesn't match neither the simulated circuit, not does it match the drawn circuit. So you have three different circuits (the one in the simulation is supposed to work). It's just a matter of wiring it up correctly...

Answer (score 1):

The voltage at the gate of the NMOS switch is on the low side, to fully switch on an NMOS you generally need a \$V_{GS}\$ of at least 3 V to switch the NMOS on. In your circuit the NMOS only gets: \$V_{GS}\$ = 3.3 V - 3 V = 0.3 V (that is if the NMOS was properly switching which it is not, the actual \$V_{GS}\$ will be more than 0.3 V because the voltage at the source will be less than 3 V) so the NMOS isn't going to be fully switched on and the NMOS is not going to operate as a switch. Instead it will work as a "source follower". The circuit can still work but it will be **inefficient**. The MOSFET will get **warm** when you're switching large currents (like more than 100 mA).

Why don't you use a P-channel MOSFET instead? A PMOS is much simpler to control in a "high side switch" like yours. Also have a look in [this document](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70611/70611.pdf) for some examples and explanations.

Another tip: **Use a dedicated module or IC**.

Modules that take +5 V and output an isolated 12 V are available. Since the 12 V output is isolated, you can connect its + 12 V to your ground and then you would have the -12 V you need.

Also **inverting** DCDC converter modules exist, these do not have an isolated output but (like your circuit) take a positive input voltage and convert it to a negative output voltage. Search for: "Inverting DCDC"

Also ICs like the common LM2596 can be used to generate negative supply rails. In the [datasheet of the LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1590836870751) there's an example schematic on page 13 showing a circuit to generate -5 V. It can be adapted to output -12 V by using the 12 V version of the LM2596 or the adjustable version with the proper voltage divider.

Also note that your circuit can **never** output an exact -12 V as it has **no feedback**, the output voltage will depend on how much you load the circuit.

**Edit:**

You're shorting the source of the NMOS to Ground through the RPi's ground! The circuit can't work that way. Study some working designs to learn how this should be done.

Comment: The gate source voltage is 3.3 volts - the gate drive is not tied to ground - it is floating.

Comment: the threshold voltage in my mosfet is about 2V , so my raspberry can switch it ,and feedback i will add its the next step , I think that I connect wrong the mosfet this is my temporary circuit ,It does not look good but I wait until the wire up comes arrives

Comment: @SalhaShomary with respect to the inverter's gnd, the raspberry's gnd is floating. Therefore the pi can't simply measure the output voltage to form a feedback loop. Are you aware of that? From that perspective, a pmos for the high-side switch would be more suitable.

Comment: pmos with low threshold voltage ?

Comment: @SalhaShomary sure, as your input voltage is quite low. Note, that you have to invert the duty cycle when using a pmos

Comment: why i should invert the duty cycle when using pmos?

Comment: @SalhaShomary An nmos conducts if the gate is HIGH (higher than source) and a pmos conducts when the gate is LOW (lower than source).

Comment: @Andyaka *the gate drive is not tied to ground - it is floating.* Yep, I see that now. And in the real "bench" schematic that's shorted to GND, what a mess :-(

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I manage to get -12V but the voltage starts to drop to almost 9.8V, why is it unstable why the voltage drops after seconds?

Comment: Like I stated in my answer: *your circuit can never output an exact -12 V as it has no feedback, the output voltage will depend on how much you load the circuit.* So, it is no surprise to me that this happens.